# NSNotification issue - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I have this observer

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(flashButtonDidPress(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "flash"), object: nil)
```

And this delegate function

```
func flashButtonDidPress(_ title: String) {
    cameraController.flashCamera(title)
}
```

Can someone explain me why I have the following error?

> unrecognized selector sent to instance

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
I am also accessing the function without the use of a notification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NotificationCenter` sends `Notification`s, not `String`s, use a second function to be called from somewhere else:

```
func flashButtonDidPress(_ notification: Notification) {
   if let title = notification.userInfo?["title"] as? String {
      flashCamera(with:title)
   }
}

func flashCamera(with title: String)
{
  cameraController.flashCamera(title)
}
```

pass the `title` in the `userInfo` dictionary when posting the notification, e.g.

```
let userInfo = ["title", title]
```